# How to include a class from a subproject

Tags: ios, xcode, class, include, subproject

(Xcode 6.1, Objective-C, iPad)

I have an Xcode project with another project--a subproject.

I am trying to #import a class from the subproject in the usual way:

```
#import "myAwesomeClass.h"
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
'myAwesomeClass.h' file not found.
```

When I open the subproject, the class is right there in the hierarchy.

How do I include a class that exists in the subproject into the main project? Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main project are looking for the subproject's headers in its root folder, so if the subproject is not "physically" a child of the main project, you will get this kind of issue.

You can explicitly set a header search path for your main project.

In Xcode, select your project, `build settings`, and under the `Search Paths` section you will find a parameter `Header Search Paths`. Add the desired paths (absolute or relative) and the headers of the subproject will be found